# read cassandra table with UDT with null values, and map to Scala case class, in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

The error shows:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Requested a TypeTag of the
>   GettableToMappedTypeConverter which can't deserialize TypeTags due to
>   Scala 2.10 TypeTag limitation. They come back as nulls and therefore
>   you see this NPE.

**gradle.build**

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.11'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'com.datastax.spark', name: 'spark-cassandra-connector_2.12', version: '2.5.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.12', version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    implementation group: 'org.scalaj', name: 'scalaj-http_2.12', version: '2.4.2'
}
```

**Scala object**

```
object SparkModule {
    case class UDTCaseClass(a: Int = 0, b: Float = 0f, c: Int = 0, d: Int = 0)
    case class TableCaseClass(id: UUID, col1: Boolean, list: List[UDTCaseClass])

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
        .master("local[2]")
        .appName("App")
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")
        .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val cassandraRDD = sc.cassandraTable[TableCaseClass](
        "keyspace", "table"
    ).limit(20)

    println(cassandraRDD.count())
}
```

At first, sometimes the error showed and sometimes it didn't, until I narrowed it down and realized it shows when any of the UDT's fields are `null`, otherwise it works just fine. For example, if the table contains any one of the following rows, the error is raised:

> f39b5201-1e96-44a8-946c-d959c217f174 | False | [{a: 123, b: 2.3, c:
>   33, d: **null**}]
>   f39b5201-1e96-44a8-946c-d959c217f174 | False | [{a: 123, b: 2.3, c: **null**, d: 34}]
>   f39b5201-1e96-44a8-946c-d959c217f174 | False | [{a: 123, b: **null**, c: 33, d: 12}]
>   f39b5201-1e96-44a8-946c-d959c217f174 | False | [{a: **null**, b: 2.3, c: 33, d: 22}]

whereas, for instance, this one:

> f39b5201-1e96-44a8-946c-d959c217f174 | False | **null**

is read just fine by `cassandraTable`.

I tried using `Option` like this:  `case class UDTCaseClass(a: Option[Int] = None, b: Option[Float] = None, c: Option[Int] = None, d: Option[Int] = None)`, but the same error appears.

I could always just insert 0s instead of `null`s but, could that be avoided?

Thanks

Comment: can you put results of `describe type ..` and `describe table ...` ?

Comment: why are you using RDD API - if you're just learning Spark + Cassandra, I would recommend to use Dataframe API instead

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine with Spark 2.4.2/Scala 2.12 and SCC 2.5.0.

For following UDT/table and data:

```
CREATE TYPE test.udt (
  id int,
  t1 int,
  t2 int,
  a2 int
);

CREATE TABLE test.u3 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    u list<frozen<udt>>
);
insert into test.u3(id, u) values (5, [{id: 1, t1: 3}]);
```

following Scala code works fine:

```scala
case class UDT(id: Int, t1: Int, t2: Option[Int], a2: Option[Int])
case class U3(id: Int, u: List[UDT])

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
val d = sc.cassandraTable[U3]("test", "u3")
d.collect
```

it returns: `Array(U3(5,List(UDT(1,3,None,None))))` as expected.

Your error could arise from a problem that you maybe not recompiled the code, or it's somehow cached...

P.S. as I pointed in the comment, if you're just starting, prefer to use Dataframe API instead - it's [fully supported by SCC](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md).